Opinion / input on visualization needed
I am about to submit my first paper and have such a graph (in the paper as a $2\times 2$ plot). The plot gives quite a lot. I have a model with two varying parameters, alpha and beta, and am examining the relationship on metric 1 ($y$-axis). I vary alpha on the $x$-axis and beta in the form of different colors. Additionally, I have varied the input (demand pattern) over all $\alpha$-$\beta$ combinations and three demand levels. This is indicated by the error bars (min and max) of each point. Unfortunately, I find the plot very overloaded and confusing. How could I make it a bit clearer? Are there other display options that would be useful?
EDIT:
Since you asked, here is the explanation. $x$ is my total cost, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are numerical parameters that go into my MILP and affect the cost. Variant $a$ is the Mixed Integer Linear Program, where the parameters are explicitly considered during the optimization, while $b$ does not consider them during the optimization, but after the solution. I vary $\alpha$ and $\beta$ 3 times each, also 9 combinations. Additionally I have a demand pattern (which is used in my MILP) and there are three levels. So I have 27 combinations for variant $a$ and 27 for variant $b$, where only nine are shown and the min and max values are shown in the error bars.


Is your $\beta$ parameter categorical (Variant 1a, vs, 2b, etc.), or is it numerical?

If you are giving us $y$ and $x$ as anonymous labels because you think the real details are irrelevant to your question or you’re reluctant to make your data public, fair enough. But they would be poor choices for a published graph.

@NickCox I added more information

This plot shows 36 data points, IIUC. Giving us a listing of data would allow people to experiment using their own software in sales pitches for different designs.

I think it looks fine, though the error bars are not easy to discern. My main suggestions would be

remove the background grid
change from yellow to a darker colour
consider doing what in ggplot2 is called 'dodging' the points (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) so that the error bars don't overlap, and
consider using separate panels for each of the variants. In fact, you can plot all lines in every panel but only show the focal line in colour and with error bars [see comment by Nick Cox below, where he calls this a front-and-back plot and adds a useful reference].
EDIT: Stephan Kolassa makes a good point below - it would be better to skip the legend and just add the names at the end of each line.


+1, though I would (a) keep the background grid, which I believe adds value, and (b) instead of a legend label each curve on the right end with "1a" and so forth. With the legend below the plot, the reader has to go back and forth to identify lines. And for people who have difficulty with color, this may actually be hard. Finally, the natural progression for western language native speakers is left-to-right and top-to-bottom, so the current legend is in inverted order to the lines themselves, which adds cognitive strain. So: label the curves, lose the legend.

@StephanKolassa Agree on the second point. My main problem with the grid is that it obscures the error bars. If 'dodged' appropriately, this would not be an issue.

@StephanKolassa I noticed your point (b) only after I posted my answer.

If a name is helpful, although it is hardly essential, I have introduced the term front-and-back plot to any design in which all groups are shown in all panels (facets) but each group in turn is shown at the front while the others are plotted as backdrop. That need not, but it might, be associated with different colours. It should be associated with greater emphasis to what @mkt is calling the focal group. https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X211025838  is a source for that term and for several references. I would be delighted to learn of other early or excellent examples.

Lose the legend! Kill the key! (if you can) are good slogans. Simple jargon sometimes used for text on the graph in place of a legend is direct labelling (labeling).  In this case there seems no point to repeating the text "Variant".

If you do want to keep the background grid, I would consider getting rid of the vertical gridlines and keeping only the horizontal. Because the data points are all at fixed, labeled x-coordinates, the vertical grid lines are not necessary to help estimate the x-coordinate. But the horizontal lines can help you easily tell, for example, that a certain data point is >12.

It all depends on the story you are trying to tell. We know that a picture is worth a thousand words. Think of the graph as a picture, which illustrates the point(s) you are trying to make, and choose the graph which illustrates that point in the simplest way (As Einstein is said to have said "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler" - easier said than done, but excellent advice).
In your graph, you have 4 variables: alpha, beta, y, and the demand level (whatever these 4 variables are...). That is kind of busy. Is it really needed to tell your story?
For example, if the main point is that "variant 3b" is the "best" at all levels of alpha, then the "error bars" are not relevant to the story, and make the graph less simple than it could/should be.
Or the story could be that the "demand level" does not change things much (the error bars are quite small)? Then show a graph just for a single variant, with 3 plots (1 for each demand level), which would illustrate that this has a small effect. And then, just with text, say that the situation is the same for all variants.
But what if the story is both of the above? Then use 2 separate graphs. Keep the story simple: what is the main plot, and what is/are the additional sub-plot(s), and do not try to cram them all on a single graph.
But since we do not know what alpha, beta, y or "demand level" are, it is difficult to go beyond the generalities I went through above: be clear about the story you are trying to tell, and illustrate it simply, one (sub-)point at a time.

Thank you very much. I added a bit more information!

Alas for a good story, but there is no evidence that Einstein really said that. https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691138176/the-ultimate-quotable-einstein discusses that and several other frequent attributions.

@NickCox, indeed, which is why I wrote that he "is said to have said it" (Einstein is one of the best "appeal to authority" one can ever use :-)

As the attribution has been squashed authoritatively, there are no grounds to repeat it.

I would avoid using the legend and add the labels right next to the lines. Here's a crude example, with only three lines labelled, but hopefully you get the idea:

Then you can avoid colours and line types altogether or use them for other purposes.
